# Use loop iteration to dynamically update dataframe name in ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

I want to use ddply in a loop, but need to change the data name based on the loop iteration, such as:

iteration 1: `ddply(df1, ...`
iteration 2: `ddply(df2, ...`
iteration 3: `ddply(df3, ...`

I've tried using something like `paste0("df",j)` in place of the data name, but that doens't work.  I've also tried

```
data <- paste0("df",j)
ddply(data, ...
```

but that doesn't work either.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Also, apologies for not preparing a working example, i'm actually working with dataframes stored in a list which would make for a complicated example.  However, I could try and distill it down into a working example if necessary.

Comment: Can you put your df's in a list and `sapply` the ddply call over that list?

Comment: Hey Joe, yes my df's are actually already in a list.  My "real" case has me using 'dfs$df1' where dfs is the list and df1 is the dataframe.  I'm basically trying to update this through iterations like 'dfs$df1', 'dfs$df2', etc.  I will do some reading on 'sapply'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list `dfs` like in comments, containing df1 df2 etc., then I imagine you could do something like

```
sapply(dfs,function(d) ddply(d,...))
```

Exactly application depends on your exact usage.

You may want to use `lapply` here instead, as it seems to give a better result format:

```
> dfx1 <- data.frame(
+   group = c(rep('A', 6), rep('B', 14), rep('C', 9)),
+   sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 29, replace = TRUE),
+   age = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54)
+ )
> 
> dfx2 <- data.frame(
+   group = c(rep('A', 6), rep('B', 14), rep('C', 9)),
+   sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 29, replace = TRUE),
+   age = runif(n = 29, min = 18, max = 54)
+ )
> 
> dfs <- list(dfx1,dfx2)
> 
> v <- lapply(dfs,function(d) ddply(d,.(group,sex),summarize,agemean=mean(age)))
> v
[[1]]
  group sex  agemean
1     A   F 26.76541
2     A   M 29.16023
3     B   F 37.63099
4     B   M 39.92033
5     C   F 35.24655
6     C   M 37.86241

[[2]]
  group sex  agemean
1     A   F 36.68879
2     A   M 36.55951
3     B   F 40.56872
4     B   M 37.60044
5     C   F 33.41869
6     C   M 42.35216

>
```

Comment: Joe,  I'm wanting to store these in a new list of dataframes using 'dfs.wtd <- vector("list",22)' and 'dfs.wtd <- sapply(dfs, function(d) ddply(d, .(A), summarise, B=weighted.mean(B,weight)))'.  I appear to be getting the correct answers, but the list/dataframes 'dfs.wtd' isn't formatted properly.  Am I making some mistake here?

Comment: If I enter 'View(dfs.wtd)' in RStudio, I get a first column 'row.names' containing 'A' in row 1 and 'B' in row 2. However, if I try 'View(dfs.wtd$df1)' which should give the first dataframe in the list, I just get a single column called 'x' that contains 'A' data but not a second column with 'B' data.

Comment: I know this is super confusing without a working example...  I could put one together if it would help.

Comment: Working examples always help.

Comment: @Thomas Here, see if `lapply` is better - see my example.

Comment: Thank you Joe, your solution with lapply gave exactly what I was looking for.  Cheers!